# Цикл вывода категорий Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день.
Есть код, который при нажатии на родительскую категорию, выводит дочерние, но скрывает родителя. Можно ли каким-то образом сделать так, чтоб родитель не скрывался, а дочерние выводились подпунктами, вот так:
-Категория
-Категория
—Субкатегория
—Субкатегория
—Субсубкатегория
-Категория

Собственно код:

```
$i=1;
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$categories = get_categories('parent='.$cat.'');
foreach ($categories as $category) { $i++; }
if ($i > 1) {
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id); ?>" ><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
<?php }
echo "</ul>";
} else {
$pcat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
$pcatid = $pcat->category_parent;
$categories = get_categories('parent='.$pcatid.'');
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
<li<?php if ($category->term_id == $cat) { ?> class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id); ?>" ><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
<?php }
echo "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот Ваша функция:
https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_categories

Как видно из документации, работает на основе: 
https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_terms

Можно с помощью **parent** определять родителя и составлять дерево.

А можно заморочиться и написать рекурсивную функцию на составление этого дерева.

Comment: Дело в том, что определять родителя и составлять дерево не совсем то. Ведь по сути он итак выводит родителей, но на странице родителя выводит только дочерние категории, а мне нужен весь список. По факту это похоже на раскрывающийся список, только которые работает постранично, а не на JS.